# Database Entity Diagrams from Existing Database, but then add relationships for documentation only

Tags: er-diagram

is there a tool that I can diagram out the relations in a database by drag dropping lines to columns but without actually creating foreign keys?

the diagrammer in sql managament studio ssms would be perfect except it creates keys in the database. I need to map out the relations for my understanding but i can't alter the database relations.

i want to point to existing database because i dont wnat to type all the columns again.

*The database I'm using is a proprietary database that we use in house (PcmsDb), but we made an OLEDB driver for it and can also export the data or the metadata. 
And I have access to a Windows a Mac and a Linux box and a Chromebook that I can use if necessary to use the tool with. For a good enough tool we'll buy whatever OS we need to use it, it would be worth it.* Anything is ok, but I prefer online tools, then windows, then ChromeOS, then Linux, then Mac, then whatever OS.

Comment: For what OS? What's your price limit? Any license considerations (e.g. allow for commercial use)?

Comment: @Izzy, `select Product, Features, ProductUrl, OS, Price, License where 1 = 1 order by price asc`

Comment: "Too many rows returned", "missing FROM clause", and the WHERE clause is a bit broad. You don't even mention what database you are talking about (MySQL, Oracle, SQLServer…). I saw you are self-answering, but still it doesn't exactly match our quality standards – see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) ;)

Comment: @Izzy, I'll have it a year from now when I forget again, as long as you don't delete it. I think closed "too broad" questions are still searchable internally and externally, correct? I think that's  a shame though; there might be some really nice answers lurking out there. My solution may not be the best one. Any filter might miss them, and closing the question will definitely miss them.

Comment: That's why I'm trying to have it improved. Not asking to make it "perfect", but to add a few basic details. Such as the database in question, the OS you (primarily) target, etc. What about phrasing it as "preferences", if you want to allow for a wider spectrum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucid Charts does it.
https://www.lucidchart.com

click the import button on entity relatino diagram it will import all tables in database for you to play with

Answer (score 0):

[Dataedo](https://dataedo.com) does that. It imports database schema to metadata repository and enables you to:

1. Draw multiple ER diagrams per database,
2. It includes existing foreign keys
3. Choose which columns to include
4. Add relations for non-existing foreing keys, only in the repository
5. Export to HTML or PDF
6. Describe each table and column serving as a Data Dictionary
7. Split database into smaller pieces - modules
8. Write descriptions using rich text and images

Currently it supports only SQL Server, Oracle and MySQL but there will be ODBC support in the future and it is possible to load tables and columns from Excel template. Later it will include database API to load metedata into repository.

It works on Windows.

PS. I'm the product manager of Dataedo

Comment: ok great and the cost?

Comment: $399 for a user for perpetual license, $239 for a 1 year license. There's a free edition but it doesn't support ERDs - just data dictionary.