# Database modelling (ERM diagrams)

Tags: windows, gratis, database, offline

I'm looking for a free (gratis) tool to create database models, i.e. ERM diagrams (entity relationship models).

The tool

- runs on Windows 10 x64
- is free (gratis)
- works offline and not in a Browser (local websites are not acceptable)
- does not use Java, because our IT does not like/allow it
- stores the diagram in a single file for easy backup purposes
- supports unlimited number of diagrams with unlimited number of tables and unlimited number of columns, because I don't know the constraints of my database yet.
- provides a GUI for graphical input, not some description language (I like those very much in general)

Non-requirements:

- multi user support, since only 1 user will use it for small database projects
- it needn't synchronize data to the cloud, backup etc. I want a single file which I can copy or delete.
- no need for importing databases or creating databases based on the model. This will all be done manually.

I have found the following potential candidates, but they don't match:

- [SQLDBM](https://sqldbm.com/), but it's online / web-based
- [Squirrel](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/), but it uses Java
- [SQL Developer](http://sqldeveloper.solyp.com/index.html), but it also uses Java
- [Quick Database Diagrams](https://www.quickdatabasediagrams.com/#pricing) can only draw 1 diagram with 10 tables
- [ERwin Data Modeller](https://erwin.com/products/data-modeler/) but it's not free, only available as a trial

Closest so far is [yEd](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed), but things like that should not happen:

[image: Manual fiddling required]

I don't want to be fiddling around manipulating the sizes of objects just to make the text fit.

I found the following questions here on SR:

- [for Android](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1440/mobile-data-model-diagrams-erd) and without an answer at the time of writing
- [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/39537/database-entity-diagrams-from-existing-database-but-then-add-relationships-for) suggests [Dataedo](https://dataedo.com/pricing), but the Lite version cannot draw diagrams

Comment: I used DeZign for Databases some time ago, but it's not free. Main advantage is ability to work with multiple databases.
http://datanamic.com/dezign/index.html